# Warum ist "stehen" in "verstehen"?

Tags: etymology

Warum ist das Verb "stehen" in "verstehen"? Gibt es eine Erklärung dafür?

Ich konnte nichts Hilfreiches dazu im Duden finden.

Ich weiß, dass es in ähn­licher Weise auch im Englischen so ist (understand-stand), vielleicht gilt die Antwort für beide Sprachen denn. Danke.

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/verstehen liefert eine Fülle von Informationen zur etymologischen Herkunft.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ , es hat mir nicht weiterholfen.

Comment: Worum spezifisch geht es Dir denn? Auf der verlinkten Seite ist die Herkunft von _stehen_ für _verstehen_ eindeutig belegt, und es gibt auch einen Link zu den diversen Präfix Versionen von stehen. Stehen hat sehr viele Bedeutungen, und kommt in vielen Wörtern vor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Verstehen* leitet sich aus althd. *firstân* ab, was aus einer Zusammensetzung der Präfix *fir-* und germ. *stē* entstand; wie diese Kombination, also wie heute *verstehen*, ihre Bedeutung erlangt hat ist umstritten ([Harm, 2003](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40849183)). Plausibel erscheint mir die Deutung Martins (1936, zit. n. [Harm, 2003:112](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40849183)), der den Bedeutungsursprung "in einem rechtssprachlichen Begriff 'vor Gericht stehen, vor Gericht für jmd. einstehen'" sieht ([Harm, 2003:112](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40849183)). Daraus "habe sich 'eine Rechtssache vertreten' entwickelt, daraus wiederum 'eine Rechtssache beherrschen', 'eine Rechtssache verstehen' und schliesslich 'eine Sache verstehen'" (ebd.).

Comment: Die Quellenangaben könnten eindeutiger sein. Gern auch mit Links ... 1936 könnte ja durchaus auf ein gemeinfreies Werk hinweisen (kommt drauf an).

Comment: @0xC0000022L You're probably right, I just updated this, I hope it's better this way.

Comment: It definitely is. Thanks a bunch!